# How to add a where clause on children and map it properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

How do I run a query on children when fetching data by the EF and mapping it using the Automapper?

Let me explain the scenario first, I have a parent and children, they can both be active or inactive. If parent is inactive then all children are inactive, if parent is active then some children can be either active or not.
Now this returns parent with children

```
return Mapper.Instance.Map<ObservableCollection<Parent>>(context.Parent.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<ParentDTOWithChildren>(Mapper.Configuration));
```

Now this is what I’m after, return active parents with active children only

```
Mapper.Instance.Map<ObservableCollection<Parent>>(context.Parent.AsNoTracking()
      .Where(p => p.IsInactive != true)
      .Select(parent => new
      {
          parent,
          Children = parent.Children.Where(c => c.IsInactive != true)
      })
      .ProjectTo<ParentDTOWithChildren>(Mapper.Configuration));
```

This second attempt produces the right sql query, however the mapping does not map correctly, the children get all the values, but the parent does not.
I found out that if I select each property manually then, the parent gets all the properties, so this works

```
Mapper.Instance.Map<ObservableCollection<Parent>>(context.Parent.AsNoTracking()
      .Where(p => p.IsInactive != true)
      .Select(parent => new
      {
         parent.Id,
         parent.Description,
         parent.Information,
         . . . 
         Children = parent.Children.Where(c => c.IsInactive != true)
     })
     .ProjectTo<ParentDTOWithChildren>(Mapper.Configuration));
```

Ideally, I’d like to select just the parent (use the middle example), and it should know how to map it, but it does not until I specify each property I want. The mapping configuration is done correctly, because the first example works just fine, is there any better way to select (map) all properties from that anonymous type to my DTO ?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

This is what made it work instead of selecting of anonymous type

Service to fetch the data.

```
Mapper.Instance.Map<ObservableCollection<Parent>>
(context.Parent.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.IsInactive != true)
.ProjectTo<ParentDTOWithChildren>(Mapper.Configuration, new {excludeInactive = true}));
```

Mapping

```
var excludeInactive = false;
CreateMap<Parent, ParentDTOWithChildren>()
.ForMember(p => p.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(parent => parent.Children.Where(child  => !excludeInactive || child.IsInactive != true)))
.ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Posting sample classes and AM configuration might help.

Answer (score 2):

Side note - if you're using the static instance of AutoMapper, get rid of "Mapper.Instance" and where you pass in "Mapper.Configuration". Those are redundant.

To your original question - no. However, you can map to an intermediate type "ParentWithChildren" that represents your anonymous type, so it would look something like:

```
Mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Parent>>(context.Parent.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(p => p.IsInactive != true)
  .Select(p => Mapper.Map<ParentWithChild>(p))
 .ProjectTo<ParentDTOWithChildren>());
```

Your configuration of Parent -> ParentWithNoChildren would include that Children piece as a MapFrom configuration.

In general, instead of mapping to an anonymous type, I create an explicit type (even if it's unknown to EF), map to it, and THEN perform any additional mapping:

EF type -> Intermediate model -> DTO

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I discovered that I did not have to use the anonymous type at all (or the intermediate model, I tried it but it was throwing an exception). While I have your attention, can you have a look at my edit, to see whether there are any potential dangers in the solution I have? Thank you for the side note, these redundant parameters will be removed soon.

Comment: Edit makes sense!